# MA(q) unit roots

Tags: unit-root, moving-average

I'm looking at this statement:

"Similarly, an MA(1) model is said to have a unit root if the estimated MA(1) coefficient is exactly equal to 1. When this happens, it means that the MA(1) term is exactly cancelling a first difference, in which case, you should remove the MA(1) term and also reduce the order of differencing by one. In a higher-order MA model, a unit root exists if the sum of the MA coefficients is exactly equal to 1." (taken from: [https://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/~rnau/Decision411_2007/411arim3.htm](https://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/%7Ernau/Decision411_2007/411arim3.htm))

Could someone help me understand 3 things about this?

(1) Does a unit root in the MA coefficients = non-stationarity?

(2) Assuming the answer to (1) is yes, how can MA(q) processes be non-stationary due to their coefficients? To clarify what I'm trying to ask: if for instance y(t) = e(t) + e(t-1), the e(t-1) has a mean of 0 and constant variance and so it seems stationary.

(3) How exactly and specifically can a unit root in the MA coefficients lead to 'cancelling' a first difference?

I'm probably missing something here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The relevant case is $y_t=\varepsilon_t-\varepsilon_{t-1}$ (minus, not plus) which results from mistakenly differencing an i.i.d. process $\varepsilon_t$.

Answer (score 1):

(1) No, unit MA-roots does not imply a non-stationary.

(3) What is meant is that over-differencing the data creates unit MA-roots.  For example, suppose the true model is stationary and satisfies
$$
\phi(B)y_t=\theta(B)w_t. \tag{1}
$$
Let $z_t = (1-B) y_t$ denote the differenced series.  Applying $(1-B)$ to both sides of (1) we find that $z_t$ satisfies
$$
\phi(B)z_t=(1-B)\theta(B)w_t, \tag{2}
$$
that is, the over-differenced series will have a unit MA-root.